# On button click ,Page is not getting intended

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So basically when I will click the register button it should direct me to the next page.I too wrote the code for this,But the button is getting clicked but it is not taking me next page.I mean next page is not getting opened.There is no error in the logcat section coming .It means my code is running ..But the page is not getting intended.

this is my new_user_login.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    tools:context=".NewUserActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="581dp"
        android:text="   REGISTRATION "
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="487dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="530dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
        android:text="EMAIL ID"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="388dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="186dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="351dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
        android:text="PHONE NO."
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="306dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="254dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_username"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usname"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="205dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="131dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passsword"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="113dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="324dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:background="@color/DeepPink"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:onClick="REGISTER"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my NewUserActivity.java class

```
public class NewUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText phone;
    EditText usname;
    EditText passsword;
    Button register;
    ToastManager toastManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_user_login);


        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        usname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usname);
        passsword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passsword);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);


        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String PHONENO = phone.getText().toString().trim();
                String username = usname.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = passsword.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";
                String phonePattern = "(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}";


                boolean isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty = !NAME.isEmpty()
                        || !EMAIL.isEmpty()
                        || !PHONENO.isEmpty()
                        || !username.isEmpty()
                        || !password.isEmpty();

                 // Create a new instance of ToastManager
                ToastManager toastManager = new ToastManager(NewUserActivity.this);
                // When one or all Edit Text are blank
                if (isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty) {
                    // NAME VALIDATION
                    if (NAME.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER NAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((NAME.length() > 3) && (NAME.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("NAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 3-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!NAME.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ONLY ALPHABETS ALLOWED", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                    //EMAIL VALIDATION
                    if (EMAIL.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER EMAIL-ID", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("INVALID EMAIL", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                   //PHONE NUMBER VALIDATION
                    if (PHONENO.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!(PHONENO.length() == 10)) {
                        toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!(PHONENO.matches(phonePattern))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                    //USERNAME VALIDATION
                    if (username.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                    //PASSWORD VALIDATION
                    if (password.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

               // Finally show all toast all screen
                toastManager.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }


    public void REGISTER(View view) {
        Button register =(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the code where i have intended next activity

```
 public void REGISTER(View view) {
        Button register =(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(p);
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.moviebookingapp2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ticket"
        android:label="Movie Booking App"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".NewUserActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".IntroductionActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".PaymentActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".DebitActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".CreditActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have created an onclick for register method, you don't have to find a button and setonclick listener to it just remove Button register......(R.id.register)

Comment: All right but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Now I have updated it would work definitely, check it out.

Comment: Write only this much : public void REGISTER(View view) {
        
        
          
                    Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                
           
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225240/discussion-between-sank-and-jamal).